# Shortcuts stop working on cyrillic layout after some amount of time

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, cyrillic

When I boot my system - all shortcuts work well - **no matter** what layout is chosen. So I just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (or in Russian it will be <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>м</kbd>) and it works!
After some amount of time (very different - may be a few hours or few minutes) it stops working. Shortcuts now begin to work only in English layout.

I don't understand what event causes this bug. Usually only 3 applications are opened during this time: skype, chromium and sublime.

Ubuntu 15.04 3.19.0-31-generic

Answer (score 1):

That's because the applications you're running support "english" keyboard shortcuts, since they're custom-defined.

"Russian" shortcuts will only work if they have been defined during development as an appropriate shortcut...

Comment: No, after a fresh system boot - everything works fine! All shortcuts (with Cyrillic layout turned on) WORK in Chromium/Sublime/etc.... and just after some amount of time - they don't. Reboot fixes the problem but only for a while